# Path.wildcard/2 case-insensitive match

Tags: path, elixir

I want to find files of certain types under a directory. The extension part can have an arbitrary character case combination.

```
Path.wildcard("/...some path.../**/*.MPG")
```

The example above would only return files having uppercase `.MPG` extension, while I'd also like to get the downcase `.mpg` files along with whatever case combinations there could occur.

Is there a way to do that without listing all possible case combinations in the `glob`? I'd like this to work on Windows, Linux and OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use square brackets to express this in `O(n)` characters instead of listing out all combinations, which would be `O(n!)`. For this case, you can do:

```
Path.wildcard("/...some path.../**/*.[mM][pP][gG]")
```

You can also create a function to do this automatically for you:

```
defmodule Main do
  def ci(<<char::utf8, rest::binary>>) do
    char = <<char::utf8>>
    "[#{String.downcase(char)}#{String.upcase(char)}]" <> ci(rest)
  end
  def ci(""), do: ""

  def main do
    IO.inspect "*.#{ci("mpg")}"
    Path.wildcard "*.#{ci("mpg")}"
  end
end

Main.main
```

```
$ ls | grep -i mpg
bar.mpG
baz.mpg
foo.MPG
$ elixir a.exs
"*.[mM][pP][gG]"
["bar.mpG", "baz.mpg", "foo.MPG"]
```

Comment: I tried the square brackets approach before and for some reason it didn't work for me. Now it does, maybe I did a mistake somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: @Dogbert, how do we handle cases when "some path" is "Some Path" or "Some path" or "SOME PATH"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597018/how-to-perform-a-case-insensitive-file-search-in-erlang-elixir